# How to refresh layout that is created programmatically?

Tags: android

I've a case like I'm creating custom layout programmatically inside `onCreateView()`. For example :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return createLayout(cView);
    }

    View createLayout(View view) {
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    linLayout.setLayoutParams(linLayoutParam);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
         TextView tv = new TextView(activity);
         tv.setId(i);
         tv.setText("TextView");
         tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
         linLayout.addView(tv);
    }

    view = linLayout;

    return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    }
```

Nah, all I want to ask is how to refresh `textview` that has an ID from `onResume()` ? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "refresh"?

Comment: you need to setText on that TextView. Refreshing layout  is not a solution for this.

Comment: that has an ID from onResume()  means?

Comment: I mean "refresh" is change a textview value inside onResume() @SarthakMittal

Comment: Call your code on onResume() everytime with desired value

Comment: I do not see you have used that container linLayout anywhere in this code . So put the sufficient code first .

Comment: tv.setId(i) is ID from textview @NadeemIqbal

Comment: @Lukmanpryg, easiest way is to define your textview as a global field in your activity

Comment: I've edited my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold your textview in hashmap with the key of textview's id. then on your resume. you can get that textview by id and refresh it.

```
private HashMap<Integer,TextView> textViews = new HashMap<>();
```

in your on create method when you create this textviews you need to put textview in hashmap.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(activity);
    tv.setId(i);
    tv.setText("TextView");
    tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
    linLayout.addView(tv);
    textViews.put(i,tv);
}
```

your onResume method should look like below

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TextView tv = textViews.get(yourId);
    tv.setText("Your Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make **TextView tv** as global and update this tv as usual.